# Ubuntu 17.10 Mouse and Keyboard not working under Xorg

Tags: keyboard, xorg, mouse, 17.10, wayland

I upgraded my Lenovo G550 from 16.04 to 17.10. Gnome under Wayland and the login screen read the laptop's keyboard and my external Logitech mouse without any problems. However, when I try to run Gnome under Xorg, Unity, or Cinnamon, the keyboard and Logitech mouse are no longer responsive. The trackpad continues to work, and I regain control once I return to the login screen.